# Joomla 3.0 Backend component

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

Kindly help us in building the component in joomla 3.0. I didn't find related search for the back end component development. I tried using the the followinh

http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on-line component creator

http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/